# Is returning a reference to the newly created object this way, a safe practice?

Tags: c++

I'm talking about the public member functions `invert` and `invert_version2`, that take a fraction object as a parameter and return a new fraction object that is an inverse of the argument object.

```
class fraction {

     public:
         fraction(long l1, long l2) {
             num = l1;
             den = l2;
         }

         const fraction& inverse (const fraction& f) {
              return fraction(f.den,f.num);
         }

         const fraction& inverse_version2 (const fraction& f) {
              return new fraction(f.den,f.num); 
         }

     private:
          long num;
          long den;

};
```

Is this a 100% safe practice? 
**This is what I think and please correct me if I'm wrong:** 
The function `inverse` creates a new fraction object on stack and even though the reference is returned, once the program execution control(any better term?) exits the function, the values in memory holding the newly created fraction object data members are lost and replaced by garbage values (or are they not???).

However the function `inverse_version2` creates the fraction object dynamically` and thus, is 101% safe.

Please clarify if the values are indeed lost in the former case (fraction object created on stack).

Comment: It is 100% safe because `inverse_version2` will prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: Why not simply return by value?  That's 100% safe, 100% works, 100% fast, and 100% leak-free.

Comment: It is 100% bad practice to return something new(d) (unless it is an allocator).

Comment: Ok, you get my intention. How do I implement it?

Comment: Returning by value involves creating copies and I want to avoid that.

Comment: A simple return by value for this tiny structure (even big structures might not suffer), maybe?

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: No, returning by value does not involve creaing copies. There is RVO and NRVO.

Comment: Deduplicator: What???????? I was taught that it involves creating a temporary object.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions on C++ today. Do you have a C++ book?

Comment: Yes, I read this book called C++ How to Program 8th Edition. I get a lot of doubts when I do my assignments. This was my first and only question today.

Comment: The author seeks information by asking questions

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are wrong. In the first case you get UB as returning reference to local object, which is destroyed, in the second it would not even compile. If you try to fix second function naive way, as dereferencing the pointer, you will get memory leak. So 100% safe variant is this:

```
     fraction inverse (const fraction& f) {
          return fraction(f.den,f.num);
     }
```

PS if you want to return a pointer to dynamically allocated object return a smart pointer:

```
     std::unique_ptr<fraction> inverse_ptr( const fraction& f) {
          return std::make_unique<fraction>(f.den,f.num);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are returning a reference to a temporary, you are toast:

   ```
   const fraction& inverse (const fraction& f) {
       return fraction(f.den,f.num);
   }
   ```
2. Are you returning a pointer or a reference to a dynamically allocated object? Decide, and correct the code!
   Anyway, neither is really a good idea.

   ```
   const fraction& inverse_version2 (const fraction& f) {
       return new fraction(f.den,f.num); 
   }
   ```

What you should do instead is just returning by value (and relying on RVO / NRVO to eliminate copies/moves), or eliminating any chance of a copy.
Or, if the object is really that big, by `std::unique_ptr`.

```
fraction inverse_v1(const fraction& f) { // Uses RVO / NRVO to eliminate temporaries
    return fraction(f.den, f.num);
}
fraction inverse_v2(const fraction& f) { // no temporaries at all
    return {f.den, f.num};
}
std::unique_ptr<fraction> inverse_v3(const fraction& f) { // smart-pointer
    return {new fraction(f.den, f.num)};
}
```

Comment: My brother, let's just forget what would be better for a while and please teach me how to return a reference to a dynamically created object that I intended to do in `inverse_version2`

Comment: You *can* do so by dereferencing the result from `new`: `return *new fraction...`. That is an extremely bad idea though, as it runs counter to convention that you must not delete any object unless you get a pointer (which should be a smart-pointer).

Comment: @AnonymousAndy are you playing a stubborn  idiot, that is a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you Deduplicator. But, that gave me an error (compilation) when I tried doing the same.

Comment: Dieter Lucking, what memory leak?

Comment: Also, Deduplicator, your `inverse_v1` is just the conventional way, right? We haven't done anything different to eliminate temporaries.

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: Yes, it is the conventional one.

Comment: So, the conventional return statement always makes copies , right? So, how are we avoiding that?

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: Return statements don't always make copies. Compilers have the capability to elide copies in many cases and they've been doing it for years. There are even terms for this; RVO (Return Value Optimization) and NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization). Even if a copy was made, have you run your code in a profiler to prove this cases an actual performance bottleneck in your program?